# ArcGIS JSAPI - web workers CORS issue

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In my JS web-application, I'm trying to store the tiles in my localstorage using web workers.
I'm using the code from [this Esri sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/exp_webstorage.html). I just deleted line 20 in the ioWorker.js file:

```
 url = "/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/proxy/proxy.ashx?" + url;
```

But when the web worker requests a tile, I get those three errors:
[image: Error]
On my side, CORS should be working fine. Is this a problem on Esri's side or have i got something wrong?

edit: Or is it not possible only with CORS, do I need a proxy-page?

Comment: From the sample: `In order to run this sample application on your machine you'll need to update the line that sets the proxy in the ioWorker.js file to point to your proxy.`. You need a local proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a proxy page if the the request is not from the same domain. The proxy also needs to be under the same domain, otherwise, you'll still get this CORS error.